# How to redirect Spark logging stdout to console

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

When my spark application fails, it logs a very generic message to the console. In order to see the detailed message, that reveals the true error, I have to go to the Spark History Server and view the stdout logs for my executor. Does anyone know how I can get additional details to appear in the console? I have been looking at a few links that point to the log4j properties file but reviewing the file I would think it is already setup correctly:

```
# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark-project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR
```

A few additional details:

- I am using PySpark
- These are errors generated from Spark SQL
- I am running with Yarn Master in Cluster Mode

Answer (score 1):

For the `log4j.properties` file to work as expected, following needs to be added to `spark-submit` (assuming `log4j.properties` is in classpath) :

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" 
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties"
```

But most importantly, you need to make sure that you doing `spark-submit` in `yarn client mode`, else your driver program will be launched in one of the nodes on your cluster and you will not see its logs on console.

For checking logs on doing `spark-submit` on `yarn cluster mode` use this (requires `yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true` in `yarn-site.xml`):

```
yarn logs -applicationId <applicationId>
```

Comment: Does this mean if I am running in cluster mode there is no way to route the output to the console? My only option is to run the yarn logs statement?

Comment: That is correct as far as i know. Printing logs on console looks more like a debugging exercise and for such purpose correct way to run spark application is on yarn client or standalone mode. Once debugging is complete switching back to cluster mode should be the right approach.